# Prove that the radical of an ideal is generated by the squarefree parts of its generating monomials.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

The squarefree part of a monomial $x^\textbf{u}$ is $\prod_{i:u_i>0}x_i$. Show that if $\textit{I} = \langle{x^{\textbf{u}_1}, ..., x^{\textbf{u}_r}}\rangle$ is a monomial ideal, then the radical $\sqrt{I}$ is generated by the squarefree parts of $x^{\textbf{u}_1}, ..., x^{\textbf{u}_r}$.

> It is a bit different than defining that an ideal generated by squarefree monomials is indeed a radical ideal, but I don't really know how to tacke it this way.

Comment: ... in other words: please show us what you have attempted so far. Read the definitions of the terms involved (monomials, monomial ideal, radical, etc.) and work with them. Say exactly where you get stuck. Otherwise, the question will probably be closed (MSE is not a homework machine).